# PHP server statistics script?

Tags: php, statistics, ram, temperature, uptime

I'm not really sure where to put this question (it's not really webapps or superuser) but I'm sure something similar already exists. I'm looking for a php script that gives me detailed info about things such as:

- CPU load
- Network load
- Temperatures
- I/O
- RAM
- etc

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Dennis

Comment: I don't know if there is a general script doing the job. But I guess it would depend to the operating system. On what system is the server running?

Comment: You can ask questions about that in the [Stackoverflow chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com). But please avoid posting open-ended questions for software recommendations here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[phpSysInfo](http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/) is good for this.

Comment: good try, how about temperature ?

Comment: @ajreal It seems to have *some* temperatures in the demo.

Answer (score 1):

These scripts are good:

- [phpSysInfo](http://phpsysinfo.github.io/phpsysinfo/): a customizable PHP script that displays information about your system nicely.
- [eZ Server Monitor](http://www.ezservermonitor.com/): a lightweight and simple dashboard monitor for Linux.
- [PHP Server Monitor](http://www.phpservermonitor.org/): a script that checks whether your websites and servers are up and running.

These scripts are [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software).